# How to enable addins on Windows Live Messenger 2011?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, windows-live-messenger

I found [this interesting article](http://communitiy.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/09/17/4431.aspx) teaching how to create an add-in for WLM.

I changed the registry but nothing new appeared. Does WLM 2011 support add-ins?

edit: I am on Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add-ins have been [pulled out since WLM 2009](http://www.winvistatips.com/enable-add-t358555.html).